# Given that tar ignored my 2 sockets, how do I backup and then restore my login folder?

Tags: macos, backup, restore, tar, sockets

I did a network backup of my login area in preparation for reformatting the volume in which it resides to make it bootable on my old Power Mac G5 *running the very latest release* of Leopard.

Though I don't believe this symptom is a function of the actual `tar` invocation, here is the actual command for completeness:

```
   bill@r2d2-2:~
   [108] (sudo tar cf - -C /Volumes/usr1 Users) | gzip -c - | ssh whmcclos@mbp \
             'cat > /Volumes/link2TMS/r2d2_usr1_Users.tar.gz'
   tar: Users/bill/Library/Acrobat User Data/8.0_ppc/Synchronizer/Commands: socket ignored
   tar: Users/bill/Library/Acrobat User Data/8.0_ppc/Synchronizer/Notification: socket ignored
```

Here are the two socket files which `tar` is ignoring

```
bill@r2d2:~/Library/Acrobat User Data/8.0_ppc/Synchronizer
[11] ls -larhdt *
drwx------  3 bill  staff   102B Jun  4  2010 metadata
-rw-r--r--  1 bill  staff     0B Jan 20 13:05 adobesynchronizersu80
srwxr-xr-x  1 bill  staff     0B Jan 20 13:05 Notification
srwxr-xr-x  1 bill  staff     0B Jan 20 13:05 Commands
```

Haven't worked with creating sockets in a few years, and I'll know what to do once I get a hint. As the Title says, how do I backup and then restore these files given that `tar` has ignored them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't.

Unix local sockets are created as soon as a program attempts to listen on the given path for connections, and despite being a type of file they only act as pointers to in-memory structures; so they are useful only as long as the program is still running (and only within the same machine; no NFS or anything such).

After the program exits, the socket file is no longer useful (and is normally deleted by the program itself); in fact, if the program gets restarted, it *has to delete the old socket* before listening on the same path – otherwise it would receive an "Address already in use" (the same as if two programs  were trying to take the same TCP port).

This is somewhat different from named *pipes* (aka fifos), which work in a much simpler way (one process writes, one process reads) and therefore are reusable; a named pipe can be created using the `mkfifo` or `mknod p …` commands.

Comment: I was indeed confusing FIFO's, which I've programmed and used, with sockets.  There are also those pesky albeit extremely important/useful `b`(lock) and `c`(character) special files in the `/dev` folder, and as I recall, they don't tar up either. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: @BillMcCloskey: tar can archive device nodes, but needs root privileges to extract them. But usually you can skip all of /dev too, since modern systems create necessary device nodes on boot.

Comment: Glad to hear that /dev file creation has evolved to be more dynamic; think I recall using `mknod` in the days of my first _slackware_ installation.  Wanting to see what I may be in for with this relatively _new_ leopard box, I did a `sudo tar cf - /dev > /dev/null`, only to see `tar: /dev/fd/3: Cannot stat: Bad file descriptor`.  As memory serves, _I think_ that's a floppy drive which I know my PPC G5 is missing, though I do have a USB floppy drive if the need ever arises!  LOL  Thanks again for your insight - most helpful.

Comment: Yes - Linux had a "devfs" for a while (though it was quite unusual); later, /dev was made a simple tmpfs in which the udev daemon created all device nodes from kernel events; this has existed for over a decade – I find references to udev's old name "kerneld" from 1997.  Recently, this was moved back to the kernel again – /dev being a special kind of tmpfs where the kernel itself makes device nodes appear (in a much simpler way than devfs did, though) and udev only adjusts modes/ownership/symlinks. I do not know about OS X, but I assume it too uses a dynamic /dev, maybe like devd in other BSDs.

Comment: As for the /dev/fd/ directory, that's not floppy drives – it contains special files corresponding to the program's own file descriptors. For example, opening /dev/fd/2 (or the /dev/stderr symlink) is equivalent to calling `dup(2)`. Generally, it is a good idea to tell backup tools to either ignore /dev completely, or to never cross filesystem mount points (assuming /dev *is* a mount point), because it is certainly useless to have backups of /dev or virtual filesystems like Linux /proc and /sys, or FreeBSD /kern.

Comment: (And yes, by saying "on boot" I actually meant "as soon as the device is detected", in any OS that supports hotplug...)

Comment: I'm using `tar`, rather than `rsync` or `dd`, but that _could_ lead to problems.  We touched upon some _special_ file & fs cases to avoid with `tar`. I'm concerned with things that don't show up right away. It may be instructive to document the important things to keep in mind when using various archivers to backup and restore _information_. For instance, handling of _ACL_, _special files_, _links_, and _SETUID_ perms should be mentioned for each archiver. Have you seen commentary or a question/answer which addresses this? I've already run into cases where some `tar` implementation strip ACL.